# ls -l with regular grep expression

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, regular-expression

we have the following 1000 files

```
ls -ltr | grep list_of_cars | sort

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   259 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-0.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   259 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-1.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   259 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-2.json
.
.
.

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   260 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-996.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   260 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-997.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   260 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-998.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   260 Dec 24 16:29 list_of_cars-999.json
```

but when I try to capture all files with `list_of_cars-[0-999].json` by the following regular syntax , we get only 10 files instead of 1000 , why?

```
ls -ltr | sort | awk '{print $NF}' | grep "^list_of_cars-[0-999].json"
list_of_cars-0.json
list_of_cars-1.json
list_of_cars-2.json
list_of_cars-3.json
list_of_cars-4.json
list_of_cars-5.json
list_of_cars-6.json
list_of_cars-7.json
list_of_cars-8.json
list_of_cars-9.json
```

where I am wrong?

Comment: Why do you `sort` `ls`' output after having it reverse sorted by modification time? Why do you do a long listing if you then extract the name only?
Wouldn't `ls list_of_cars-[0-9]*.json` do? If you need to exclude some files, e.g. >1000, why not `ls list_of_cars-{0..999}.json` (should your shell allow for it)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Preliminary note**: Using basic regular expression (the default) in `grep` forces to backslash escape quite a few meta-characters (see "Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions" in [`grep` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)). I avoided those extra escapes in my examples below, so you should use them as extended regular expression with `grep -E <regexp>` (or escape the relevant meta-characters yourself).

---

In a regexp `[0-999]` means "match exactly one character in range 0-9 or 9 or 9"

What you are looking for is (I'll go for the easiest first) "match any number of characters in the range 0-9" which would translate to `[0-9]*`.

Note also that `.` matches any character. To match a period exactly, you have to escape the value as `\.`

So your final regexp would be `^list_of_cars-[0-9]*\.json`

Now, this will match 0 or more digits, thus `list_of_cars-.json` would match. We could restrict one step by asking "match one or more characters in range 0-9" which would be `^list_of_cars-[0-9]+\.json`

We could be even more restrictive by specifying "match 1 to 3 characters in range 0-9" if you really want to make sure you don't get results over 999 => `^list_of_cars-[0-9]{1,3}\.json`